# Speed up multiple Do loop

Tags: iteration, do

I am writing a script to simulate the multi spin system and for that I need to use three successive iterations. The code runs fine but takes a long time. I need the final FID. So, has there a way to speed up the loop?

Here is the main part of the code:

```
F[t_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = 
  Integrate[(\[Omega]D (\[Sqrt]2 Sin[
         2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] - (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 \
Cos[2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]]) ), t];
G[t_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = 
  Integrate[(\[Omega]CS (-\[Sqrt]2 Sin[
         2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] + (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 \
Cos[2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]])), t];
FID = Table[0, {Length@time - 1}];
Do[
 Do[
  Do[
   \[CapitalDelta]F = Differences@Re@F[time, \[Beta], \[Gamma]];
   \[CapitalDelta]G = Differences@Re@G[time, \[Beta], \[Gamma]];
   integrals = (TensorProduct[\[CapitalDelta]F[[i]], (2 I1z.I2z - 
         I1x.I2x - I1y.I2y)] + 
      TensorProduct[\[CapitalDelta]G[[i]], (I1z + I2z)]);
   U = MatrixExp[-I*integrals];
   \[Rho] = U.\[Rho]2.U\[ConjugateTranspose];
   FID[[i]] = FID[[i]] + Tr[(I2x + I I2y)\[ConjugateTranspose].\[Rho]];
   , {i, 1, Length@time - 1}]
  , {\[Gamma], 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/10}]
 , {\[Beta], 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/100}]
```

where the constant parameters are as follows:

```
Ix = 1/2 {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}; Iy = 1/2 {{0, -I}, {I, 0}}; Iz = 
  1/2 {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}; Io = IdentityMatrix[2];
I1z = KroneckerProduct[Iz, Io];
I2z = KroneckerProduct[Io, Iz];
I1x = KroneckerProduct[Ix, Io];
I2x = KroneckerProduct[Io, Ix];
I1y = KroneckerProduct[Iy, Io];
I2y = KroneckerProduct[Io, Iy];
 aq = 30(*ms*); DwL = 0.004(*Dwell time in ms*);
 time = Table[i, {i, 0, aq, DwL}];
  \[Omega]D = 2 \[Pi] 0.4*5; \[Omega]CS = 2 \[Pi] 0.4*10; \[Omega]r = 
   2 \[Pi] 30;
 \[Rho]2 = {{0.49999999999924505` - 5.3248107710933424`*^-30 I, 
  6.523670492691303`*^-13 + 3.9834802123513276`*^-13 I, 
  0.49999999999951283` + 
  1.3500311979420732`*^-13 I, -2.0194839173657902`*^-28 + 
  0.` I}, {6.523670492691303`*^-13 - 
  3.9834802123513276`*^-13 I, -0.4999999999997806` + 
  0.` I, -8.095685041233708`*^-29 + 7.573064690121713`*^-29 I, 
  0.49999999999951283` + 
  1.3500311979420732`*^-13 I}, {0.49999999999951283` - 
  1.3500311979420732`*^-13 I, -8.095685041233708`*^-29 - 
  7.573064690123722`*^-29 I, 
  0.4999999999997806` - 2.7610131924492357`*^-30 I, 
  6.523670492691301`*^-13 + 
  3.9834802123513287`*^-13 I}, {-2.0194839173657902`*^-28 + 
  9.183549615799121`*^-41 I, 
  0.49999999999951283` - 1.3500311979420732`*^-13 I, 
  6.523670492691301`*^-13 - 
  3.9834802123513287`*^-13 I, -0.49999999999924505` + 0.` I}}
```

Any lead will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: `\[CapitalDelta]F = Differences@Re@F[time, \[Beta], \[Gamma]];` and
`\[CapitalDelta]G = Differences@Re@G[time, \[Beta], \[Gamma]]; `do not depend on `i` and can therefore be taken out of the innermost loop over `i`.

Comment: `ΔF = Differences@Re@F[time, β, γ];` unless you really want to calculate discrete differences, why not use FTOC since `F` and `G` are integrals w.r.t `t` ? Then you don't have to make a big list and calculate differences.

$$ $$
`(TensorProduct[ΔF[[i]], (2 I1z . I2z - I1x . I2x - 
     I1y . I2y)] + TensorProduct[ΔG[[i]], (I1z + I2z)])` 


`ΔF[[i]]` and `ΔG[[i]]` are numbers so `TensorProduct` is the same as elementwise multiplication (I.e. `ΔF[[1]]*(2 I1z . I2z - I1x . I2x - I1y . I2y)`)
$$ $$
You can remove all `Do` loops using FTOC, and summing `ρ` on your values of `γ` and `β`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As also noted in the comments, some quantities can be initialized outside the loops; then one only needs to define a grid and perform the valuation:

```
fDiff[b_, g_] = Differences@Re@F[time, b, g];
gDiff[b_, g_] = Differences@Re@G[time, b, g];
int[b_, g_] := TensorProduct[fDiff[b, g], (2 I1z . I2z - I1x . I2x - I1y . I2y)] + 
               TensorProduct[gDiff[b, g], (I1z + I2z)];
uMat[b_, g_] := MatrixExp[-I*#] & /@ int[b, g];
\[Rho]Mat[b_, g_] := Dot[#, \[Rho]2, #] & /@ uMat[b, g];
tr[b_, g_] := Tr[(I2x + I I2y)\[ConjugateTranspose] . #] & /@ \[Rho]Mat[b, g];

(* reduced grid *)
grid = Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, Range[0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/(20)], Range[0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/(10)]], 1];

res = Total[Map[Function[a, tr[a[[1]], a[[2]]]][#] &, grid], {1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {702.987, Null} *)
```

[image]